# In Nejimaki Seirei Senki: Tenkyou no Alderamin what happens to the spirit if his 'owner' dies?

Tags: alderamin-on-the-sky

If the owner of the spirit dies, can the spirit chose another human?
And what happens if the spirit and the human are separated?  Will it obey someone else and if yes, under what circumstances?

Comment: On [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%AD%E3%81%98%E5%B7%BB%E3%81%8D%E7%B2%BE%E9%9C%8A%E6%88%A6%E8%A8%98_%E5%A4%A9%E9%8F%A1%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB%E3%83%87%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3#.E7.94.A8.E8.AA.9E), it's mentioned that "*if the human partner is dead, they will make a new contract with the family members/friends, or find a new partner by wandering to various places*" (no citation yet though)